# Play D Scale Tune on A Scale Bansuri

Tags: scales, indian-classical, bansuri, saptak

Please confirm if it is possible to play D scale tune on A scale Bansuri, i.e convert

`Sa` `Re` `Ga` `Ma` `Pa` `Dha` `Ni`

to

`Ma` `Pa` `Dha` `Ni` `Sa` `Re` `Ga`

According to this, it will work for Chinese bamboo flute, [Playing Chinese bamboo flute of key "D" as "C"?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/83077/playing-chinese-bamboo-flute-of-key-d-as-c)

For instance, if D scale of O RE PIYA is

```
P...M(T)DPM(T)G...R...M(T)G...
GM(T) PD...PM(T)
M(T)DPM(T)PDN....G...N
```

would get moved up 3 notes on A Bansuri, i.e.

```
S...N(T)RSN(T)D...P...N(T)D...
DN(T) SR...SN(T)
N(T)RSN(T)SRG....D...G
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shifting the scale like this won't really work on a Bansuri, and even more generally for a composition that is *raga* based. This is because the relative pitches of successive notes are not the same, or in other words Indian classical music does not use an [equal tempered scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equal_temperament).

You could try shifting the notes and playing the song, but it will sound slightly out of tune to a trained ear.

---

(My expertise does not lie in Western classical music, so if I am using the terminology "equal temperament" incorrectly, then I would be happy to be corrected by someone knowledgeable on these matters.)

Comment: `equal tempered scale` Wow that is an excellent point. I tried playing straight D, then I tried shifting for A-scale Bansuri .... I guess I didn't notice the difference since I still need lot of practice with speed, and making half note.